# convert html to pdf and auto rotate and size large pages

Tags: .net, html, pdf

I need to convert HTML to PDF.

I've looked into a couple of different tools.

[ActivePDF WebGrabber](http://www.activepdf.com/products/serverproducts/webgrabber/index.cfm)

- did not parse our pages correctly, just returned error codes

[ExpertPDF HtmlToPdf Converter](http://html-to-pdf.net/)

- Parses correctly

Those are the two I've actualy downloaded the sdk and played around with I've also done some basic research on a few others.

The problem I have is that I need to be able to format the documents to have different page sizes and orientations which I can't seem to find much support for.

For example any page that has an img tag on it that is too big to fix on the page potrait should have its page rotated and made a3 (and probably a few more rules like this).

The second option does have some kind of api to do this.

```
pdfConverter.HtmlElementsMappingOptions.HtmlTagNames = new string[] {"IMG"};

var x =pdfConverter.GetPdfDocumentObjectFromUrl(textBoxWebPageURL.Text);

foreach(HtmlElementMapping mapping in pdfConverter.HtmlElementsMappingOptions.HtmlElementsMappingResult)
{
    foreach (var rectangle in mapping.PdfRectangles)
    {
        if (rectangle.Rectangle.Width + rectangle.Rectangle.Left > 595)
        {
             x.Pages[rectangle.PageIndex].Orientation = PDFPageOrientation.Landscape;
             x.Pages[rectangle.PageIndex].PageSize.Width = 842;
             x.Pages[rectangle.PageIndex].PageSize.Height = 1190;
        }
    }
}

x.Save(outFile);
```

The issue is that it seems that the rectangle will never be outside of the page as it has already been clipped off and the code to change the page size is never hit.

Are there any other options out there that may provide something like this functionality?

Comment: You could script a browser print to PDF...

Answer (score 0):

I run a service called [DocRaptor](http://docraptor.com/), which converts HTMl to PDF using an HTTP POST request. If you know which pages need images resized, that's easy to solve.

However, it doesn't auto-detect images that are too large to fit, though this could be handled using CSS.